# Can the data in HSQLDB (Hyper)SQLDB be persisted to the file system

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

Technologies used:
Spring 3.2 (Java framework)
Hibernate 3.6 (ORM)
HSQLDB (embedded DB)

Current configuration in Spring is as follows:

```
<!-- Data-source -->
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />

<!-- Session Factory database -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="au.com.afgonline.pce.model" />
    <!-- <property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" /> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->  
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Template -->
<bean id="hibernateTemplatePce" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Where do we specify the folder location for HSQLDB to save the data back to the file system?

Comment: Generally speaking, embedding the DB engine is only for testing purposes, and your DB should be run as an external process for real use. What are you trying to accomplish? You can persist an embedded database, but you'll have to configure it manually instead of using `jdbc:embedded-database`.

Comment: Can you point us in the right direction to help us configure? A article or example will help.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-makes-use-embedded-easy